# Inputs vertical-align:middle in td, but not text?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Why would text and controls inside the table cells ignore/not inherit `vertical-align:middle;` style of the cell itself (or row, or both)?

In CSS stylesheet loaded by the page:

```
tr.troptions{
    vertical-align:middle;
}

td.tdoptions{
    white-space:nowrap;   
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

The inspector is showing that style is applied:

[image]

but everything inside the row does not appear aligned vertically at the middle in IE10 that this is being developed for:

[image]

The CheckBoxes probably are centered vertically, but not text and not the TextBoxes. The left text box is lower than the the right.

The controls seem to be vertically aligned fine in Firefox though, but still not text:

[image]

Tried putting the style into `td`, `tr` and `table` to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I challenge everyone who downvoted this "bad" question to produce a CSS that vertically middle-aligns text, check boxes, radio buttons, text boxes and buttons in the table cells for IE10. And if you cannot - you know what you are: all-hat-no-cattle.

Comment: are the labels(text) inside a label tag,span,p, or div ?

Comment: vertical-align in td , centers the whole content but is not inherited by inline-box included wich stands on the baseline.

Comment: @GCyrillus What are you referring to as 'inline box included'?

Comment: imput are inline-boxes and behave like text too, standing on baseline. they can receive vertical-align:middle to stand on middle of baseline :) among text or other inline-boxes

Comment: You are contradicting the screenshots above - the inputs are centered, while plain text is not, at least in FF. IE is a mess, so what is going on in IE does not seem to follow any of the offered here theories. I am going to try to align everything using the margins and see.

Comment: Please provide full code, and a fiddle would be helpful.

Comment: just try vertical-align on input and give a check on W3C for definition :) . play with this :) as well http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rmxpo

Comment: @GCyrillus Does not work. I applied that directly to the text boxes but nothing changed.

Comment: can you provide your html and css in a fiddle or codepen where we can see it happening ? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know why this happens, but in general, you can use

```
.troptions {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

For Text, you can also use `line-height: 00px` where 00 is the same as `height`.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but what you stated contradicted http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp: "The text in a table is aligned with the text-align and vertical-align properties." What am I missing?

Comment: vertical-align applies to td/th or display:table-cell for content and to any inline/inline-boxe element using baseline or highest inline-element as reference. you should reformulate your answer or delete it :)

Comment: Right, my answer is not right, edited it a bit to just suggest